# how to use Leaflet.draw editing activate

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am unsure on what I need to do to make the editing functionality of leaflet.draw to work.  I create a shape but the edit button remains greyed out afterwards.  My code for it is the same as the read me as far as I know.

```
// Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
},
draw:{
    rectangle: false,
    circle: false
}
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

// On Shape/Line/Marker completion
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

if (type === 'marker') {
    // Do marker specific actions
}

// Do whatever else you need to. (save to db, add to map etc)
map.addLayer(layer);
});

// On Editing Completion
map.on('draw:edited', function (e) {
var layers = e.layers;
layers.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    //do whatever you want, most likely save back to db
});
});
```

I made sure I had the feature group set as the readme made it pretty clear that that was required, but I couldn't find anything else about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually worked this out.  You need to change the code from the provided code to add the shapes to the `drawnItems` layer instead of to `map`.

```
// On Shape/Line/Marker completion
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
var type = e.layerType, 
    layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'marker') {
    // Do marker specific actions
    }

// Do whatever else you need to. (save to db, add to map etc)
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer) // previously map.addLayer(layer);
});
```